# Apache htaccess - redirection loop during match any chars

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

as I suppose I have a simple case...

I had RewriteRule in .htaccess file which looked like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:abc|bca|cab)$ page.html
```

The goal of this rule was to redirect to page.html when url looks like e.g. http://website.com/abc
and It worked.

Now I have to change it to be more responsive and I made change to this:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ page.html
```

In this rule it should match any characters which are not '/' and this rule leads to redirection loop. After this change I got **Internal Server Error** page and error log from Apache:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace
```

I tried to add [L] flag but It didn't help.
I have no idea what happen, it should work..

Comment: You need to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before your `RewriteRule` to stop rewriting for files

Comment: @anubhava Great! It works but could you explain me in details what this condition exactly do? and what mean every part of it ?

Comment: @anubhava and I need to add the same condition before each similar rule or I can use only one for couple of rules?

Comment: This `RewriteCond` should be added before each `RewriteRule` if that pattern can match an existing file.